# Linear Regression model with multiple varibles throws error

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm starting with R and regressions and ran into a weird problem on something I thought is a simple task...
I tried to create a linear regression model from this sample dataset from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/kumarajarshi/life-expectancy-who).

The model I created should fit the life expectancy relative to a few parameters. All works fine, but when I add 'Total expenditure' to my parameter list the model function throws an error on line 13:

`Error in contrasts<-(*tmp*, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :`

Here's my code:

```
library(readr)

LE <- read_csv("Life_Expectancy_Data.csv")
head(LE)
View(LE)
# subset 2015
LE_2015 <- subset(LE, LE$Year == 2015)
LE_2015[c(1,3,4,7, 13, 14)]

# works
model <- lm(LE_2015$`Life expectancy` ~ LE_2015$Status + LE_2015$Alcohol + LE_2015$Polio)
# doesn't work
model <- lm(LE_2015$`Life expectancy` ~ LE_2015$`Total expenditure`+ LE_2015$Status + LE_2015$Alcohol + LE_2015$Polio)

print(model)
```

I'd be happy if someone can help me,
thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at your "Total expenditure" column in `LE_2015`? It only has values for the first two countries. The rest are `NA`. That's why the model doesn't know what to do with it. Incidentally, you shouldn't use `LE_2015$variable1 ~ LE_2015$variable2` inside the formula of an `lm`. Just use `lm(variable1 ~ variable2, data = LE_2015)`

Comment: Thanks - I thought the model would just not use the factor in these lines. Didn't know the lines are completely thrown out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the total expenditure column as Allan has already alluded to. The model filters out all rows that contain missing values for the variables that you use. When filtering out all missing values for total expenditure, you only have one unique value for status. That's why it throws that particular error.

I would advice you to just remove the total expenditure column. However, just to be complete. You could also turn the status column into two columns.

```
library(mltools)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
onehot <- as.data.table(LE_2015$Status) %>% one_hot()
LE_Final <- cbind(onehot, LE_2015)


model <- lm(LE_Final$`Life expectancy` ~ LE_Final$`Total expenditure` + LE_Final$Alcohol + LE_Final$Polio+ LE_Final$V1_Developed + LE_Final$V1_Developing)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to you and Allen for the quick answer and the explanation.